# Webpack генерирует код из пустого js файла

Tags: webpack

Разбираюсь с вебпаком, на данный  момент у меня самая обычная структура:

```
- dist 
    - fonts
    - images
    - less
        - app.less
    index.html
    index.js
```

В index.js подключается app.less, из которого на выходе получается единый css файл. Контент index.js:

```
import './less/app.less'
```

Больше в index.js нет ничего. Но после сборки, в index.js появляется минифицированный код:

```
!function(e){var t={};function r(n){if(t[n])return t[n].exports;var o=t[n]={i:n,l:!1,exports:{}};return e[n].call(o.exports,o,o.exports,r),o.l=!0,o.exports}r.m=e,r.c=t,r.d=function(e,t,n){r.o(e,t)||Object.defineProperty(e,t,{enumerable:!0,get:n})},r.r=function(e){"undefined"!=typeof Symbol&&Symbol.toStringTag&&Object.defineProperty(e,Symbol.toStringTag,{value:"Module"}),Object.defineProperty(e,"__esModule",{value:!0})},r.t=function(e,t){if(1&t&&(e=r(e)),8&t)return e;if(4&t&&"object"==typeof e&&e&&e.__esModule)return e;var n=Object.create(null);if(r.r(n),Object.defineProperty(n,"default",{enumerable:!0,value:e}),2&t&&"string"!=typeof e)for(var o in e)r.d(n,o,function(t){return e[t]}.bind(null,o));return n},r.n=function(e){var t=e&&e.__esModule?function(){return e.default}:function(){return e};return r.d(t,"a",t),t},r.o=function(e,t){return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e,t)},r.p="",r(r.s=0)}([function(e,t,r){"use strict";r.r(t);r(1)},function(e,t,r){}]);
//# sourceMappingURL=bundle.js.map
```

Не понимаю, откуда он берется? Это работа babel'а?

Comment: подключать less saas и css файлы лучше в entry point через запятую: `entry: {app:  ['./index.js', './scss/app.scss', './css/theme.css'],}`  или вообще без .js файла, только `['./style.less']`. Правда в итоге вы получите совсем пустой .js файл, но его легко удалить плагином https://github.com/webdiscus/webpack-remove-empty-scripts для webpack 5 и другими для других версий вебпака

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, это называется `webpackBootstrap`. `webpackBootstrap` - это IIFE (immediately-invoked function expression) функция, которая изолирует логику для загрузки и кеширования модулей.

`webpack` создает кеш (`var t = {}`) (в концепции `webpack` это называется `installedModules`), а также свою реализацию `require` (`__webpack_require__`):

```
function r <-- сокращенно от `require` (n)....
```

Функция параметром принимает идентификатор модуля. В этой функции идет проверка на то, что модуль уже загрузился и находится в кеше:

```
if(t[n]) return t[n].exports;
```

Если нет `webpack` вызывает фабричную функцию экспорта. Из этого мы можем видеть, что независимо от того, сколько модулей зависит от конкретного модуля, модуль будет загружен один раз и засеттен в кеше через:

```
installedModules[moduleId] = {
  i: moduleId,
  l: false,
  exports: {}
};
```

Благодаря этому модули могут без проблем коммуницировать, потому что возвращается ссылочный адрес того же объекта, поэтому, если модуль изменяет значение свойства в объекте, то он синхронизируется с другими объектами, которые зависят от этого модуля.

Из-за того, что `require` не поддерживается на клиенте - `webpack` предоставляет свою надстройку для возможности коммуникации между всеми модулями. Также там есть вспомогательные функции, которые проверяют к какой-то системе относится модуль (`ES || commonjs`). Это можно вынести в отдельный файл с помощью:

```
optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: true
}
```